# Just wanted to thank this community

Tags: discussion

I know I technically shouldn't be posting this, but it is Meta and you guys have a very poor reputation, it seems, among the mods on other communities. So I just wanted to say GREAT JOB!

Questions I'm not allowed to ask on the other communities, important questions, this forum has embraced and answered.

Comment: What other communities do we have a poor reputation with? Or, perhaps more importantly, why?? :(